# "See somebody do" and "see somebody doing"

Tags: grammar, verbs

My grammar book says that if you saw the **complete** action you use **do/get/drive**: "I saw him **fall** off the wall." Otherwise you use **-ing**: "I saw him **standing** at the bus stop."

A native American speaker said that he doesn't agree with that and there is no difference whether you use **-ing** or not. He said that particularly in these situations I can use either verb without affecting the meaning:

> —How do you know I took the money? —I know it because I saw you **take / taking** it.
>
> —How did the woman fall? —I don't know. I didn't see her **fall / falling**.

---

He couldn't come up with a situation where this rule makes sense. But I tried to come up with such situation and he said that in this case it can be true.

> I saw him **eat** the whole plate of pasta.

He ate everything that was on the plate. I saw him finish it.

> I saw him **eating** the whole plate of pasta.

I saw how he was eating from a plate full of pasta. But I'm not sure whether he ate everything or not. I didn't see him finish it.

---

Please comment on what has been said. And give your opinion about this rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both you and your informant are correct in different circumstances.

The difference lies in the character of the verb involved. With a *telic* verb—one which includes an end, a specific goal or point of completion—there is a marked difference between the simple form and the progressive form: the progressive form marks the action as incomplete. *Eat*, *fall*, *take* are telic verbs.

With an *atelic* verb, which does not include an end, there is no practical difference. *Stand*, *run*, *think* are ordinarily atelic verbs (although in some circumstances they may be ‘recategorized’).

See the tag-wiki entry on [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

Comment: I'd say that there is a clear difference for *stand*, at least: "I saw him stand" = he changed from not-upright to upright while I watched, while "I saw him standing" = he was upright for the entire time that i watched him.

Comment: @Hellion Right, *stand* has two senses, and "I saw him stand" would ordinarily be understood in the telic inchoative sense. But "He stood on the corner, and I saw him stand there" is unambiguously atelic.

Comment: Each of your answer is an institute in itself. Hats off @StoneyB. I always wondered what word to use which should not mean *informer* but should mean someone who informs! *Informant* is the word!

Comment: Do my first two examples (*take/taking, fall/falling*) sound different to you with different verbal forms?

Comment: @Graduate Ordinarily we would say "I saw him take it" to describe my witnessing a theft, but "I saw him tak<b>ing</b> and shouted at him to stop" would probably mean I interrupted the theft, and perhaps prevented it.

Answer (score 1):

Welll...I have to play devil's advocate.  Yesterday, this guy was sitting on the corner bench.  He got up and stood there for a while.  I know, because I saw him do it.  Isn't that also described by your sentence?  I see what you are working on, but it's very difficult to make it unambiguous IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that as a comment.