# Is it correct to say "I saw Tom opening the door"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Or should I say

> I saw Tom open the door.

I want to know if there is a difference in meaning between using "verb + noun + infinitive" and "verb + noun + gerund" in case both are grammatically correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [**"See somebody do" and "see somebody doing"**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/see-somebody-do-and-see-somebody-doing) + [**“I heard him sing.” Vs. “I heard him singing.”**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100653/i-heard-him-sing-vs-i-heard-him-singing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatically correct, but whether or not it correctly conveys your intended meaning is another matter.

The issue isn't one of being grammatically correct but being correct in meaning as each conveys a somewhat different meaning. Saying "I saw Tom open the door" has the effect of conveying that I saw him complete the action, whereas saying "I saw Tom opening the door" has the effect of conveying that I saw him in the process of completing the action or even possibly in the process of me completing the action, that I was the one opening the door when I saw him, an ambiguity that would hopefully be clarified by context, because while a comma before "opening" would clarify it wasn't Tom opening the door, no comma would leave the meaning ambiguous to many readers as to who was opening the door.

Comment: Well answered. And the Gerund?

Comment: The gerund, or gerund phrase, is "opening the door." It's ambiguous what it modifies. One way to clarify that would be to put a comma beforehand, making it clear it's an absolute phrase that modifies the entire sentence, thus clearly establishing the subject-verb "I saw" is being modified by the gerund, meaning "I" is who is "opening the door." Another way to clarify it would be to change "Tom" to "Tom's," the possessive case before a gerund making it adjectivally modify the gerund and thus clear that "Tom" is who is opening the door. As it stands, what the gerund modifies in ambiguous.